# Print and count unique values from an .xlsx file to another column in the excel sheet using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm fairly new to Excel VBA and still learning the ropes, so I need help with a step by step program without using any functions. I understand how to count through an unknown column range and output the quantity. However, for this program, I'm trying to loop through a column, picking out unique numbers and counting its frequency.

So I have an excel file with random numbers down column A. I only put in 20 numbers but let's pretend the range is unknown. How would I go about extracting the unique numbers and inputting them into a separate column along with how many times they appeared in the list?

I have a code, but it's not working and I don't know why.

```vb
Public Sub CreateInventoryReport()
Dim bcode As Long
Dim ubcode As Long
'Below is the part that is not working
If Worksheets("Sheet 2").Range("A1")<>" Then
    ' First Value Is unique
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("D5") = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1")
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("E5") = 1
Else
    r = MsgBox("no data", , "no data")
    Exit Sub
End If
bcode = 2

Do While Worksheets("Sheet 2").Cell(bcode, 1) <> ""
    ubcode = 5
    IsMatch = False
    Do While Worksheets("Sheet 2").Cell(ubcode, 4) <> ""
        If Worksheets("Sheet 2").Cell(bcode, 1) = Worksheets("Sheets2").Cell(ubcode, 4) Then
            Worksheets("Sheet 2").Cell(ubcode, 5) = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cell(ubcode, 5) + 1
            IsMatch = True
            Exit Do
        End If
        ubcode = ubcode + 1
    Loop
    If IsMatch = False Then
        Worksheets("Sheet2").Cell(ubcode, 4) = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cell(bcode, 1)
        Worksheets("Sheet 2").Cell(ubcode, 5) = 1
    End If
    bcode = bcode + 1
Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: What's the name of your sheet? Sometimes it's written sheet2 and sometimes it's sheet 2. Also you should indent your code it would make it more readable.

Comment: There is a missing " on the `If Worksheets ...` line.

Comment: Looks like a homework problem to me? No Functions, why not?

Comment: To easily check if an item is unique, you can use a `Collection`, `Dictionary` or `ArrayList` item.  The first is built-in to VBA, and will return an error if you try to add an item with a duplicate key (which you can check for). The others require binding of the appropriate object, and have a built-in method to check for duplicates.  Your code, with no indentation or spacing, is difficult to read so I'm not going to bother.